# What permissions are necessary for a Guest (Sandbox) User to see a Salesforce Site?

Tags: visualforce, permissions, site.com

I've got a Site that works as expected when I'm logged in, but I get this error as Guest User:

```
Error during init : Component class not found: markup://aura:integrationServiceApp
```

I understand that I need to give Guest User enough permissions to see the fields/objects displayed in the Site, but this error feels like a higher level problem of certain Apex components not being available to the Guest User? Google says this error comes up mostly during package installs which isn't what I'm trying to do here.

Visualforce page I'm trying to expose:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
  <h1>SWEDU Event Dashboard</h1>
                <analytics:reportChart ReportId="00O17000000WEE4"></analytics:reportChart>
</apex:page>
```

Other things to know:

- I'm doing this in a Sandbox
- This is the actual URL: http://sweduopseb-4pt0.cs22.force.com/swedudash
- My debug log wasn't very enlightening, do I need more detail in a certain area to catch this error?

  35.0 APEX_CODE,DEBUG;APEX_PROFILING,INFO;CALLOUT,INFO;DB,INFO;SYSTEM,DEBUG;VALIDATION,INFO;VISUALFORCE,DEBUG;WORKFLOW,INFO
  03:07:31.021 (21339797)|EXECUTION_STARTED
  03:07:31.021 (21374309)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|066170000000oMy|VF: /apex/SWEDU_Event_Dashboard
  03:07:31.100 (100170596)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
  03:07:31.100 (100170596)|LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
    Number of SOQL queries: 0 out of 100
    Number of query rows: 0 out of 50000
    Number of SOSL queries: 0 out of 20
    Number of DML statements: 0 out of 150
    Number of DML rows: 0 out of 10000
    Maximum CPU time: 0 out of 10000
    Maximum heap size: 0 out of 6000000
    Number of callouts: 0 out of 100
    Number of Email Invocations: 0 out of 10
    Number of future calls: 0 out of 50
    Number of queueable jobs added to the queue: 0 out of 50
    Number of Mobile Apex push calls: 0 out of 10

  03:07:31.100 (100170596)|CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE_END

  03:07:31.100 (100226286)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|VF: /apex/SWEDU_Event_Dashboard
  03:07:31.101 (101250370)|EXECUTION_FINISHED

Thanks, hope this is obvious to someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use analytics tag on sites.

See the below thread

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AyT2IAK

Since guest users won't have permission to run reports you won't be able to use vf component involving SFDC reports.

You can use any third party libraries or vf charting to rework your report .